# jquery ajax get json array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i use $.getJSON to call php file. it echos this back.

```
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    $nr[] = $i;
}

echo "{'result': 'error', 'count': '$nr'}";
```

in jquery to get result i just use

alert(data.result)

how do i get all the nr:s in count?

EDIT: But how do i loop the array through in jquery? All the keys are numeric and i dont know how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert your PHP array into an JSON array:

```
echo "{'result': 'error', 'count': ".json_encode($nr)."}";
```

You can even build your hole response message with native PHP types first and then convert it with `json_encode`:

```
$response = array(
    'result' => 'error',
    'count'  => array()
);
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $response['count'][] = $i;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: dont u mean json object? it seems like an object when you use the dots . to retrieve values:)

Comment: @fayer: The whole response value is an object with the members *result* and *count* where *result* is a string and *count* is an array. *result* can then be accessed with `data.result` and *count* with `data.count`.

Answer (score -1):

... and you can loop through the values in jQuery with the [.each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) method.